# Continuous selection given both upper and lower hemicontinuity

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

Suppose that $X,Y$ are compact metric spaces, and $g:X\rightarrow Y$ is a multivalued mapping that is both upper and lower hemicontinuous.  Is there a single valued continuous selection of $g$?  If it helps, $X$ and $Y$ are compact subsets of finite dimensional normed spaces, but $g(x)$ is not convex, in general.

Comment: Since Michael's theorem does not apply, is there some other well known result in set-valued analysis that covers this situation?  A reference would be greatly appreciated.  